# Does Google access my iCloud email through Gmail app

Tags: icloud, email, gmail

If I use the Gmail iPhone and iPad apps for my iCloud email, can Google access my iCloud email that is shown in the Gmail app?

Do they and can they?

Answer (score 1):

If you enter your iCloud password into any app or code (including safari or Apple OS devices), it surely can act on your behalf. Whether that app saves the password securely or not or retransmits any or all of the data or has a switch or timer to enable this periodically is a lot harder to discern.

Comment: What is a switch and timer?

Comment: I used an app specific one time password

Comment: App specific passwords are the best you can do. Switch or timer would be something that changes in the app after it’s reviewed. That sort of thing doesn’t get caught immediately and sometimes much later or might go unchallenged. I’m certainly not saying Google does that, but it’s been done and can’t be ruled out. To target ads, Google has to scan the contents of mails. Whether they only do that with Gmail is going to be hard for us to tell, @user32613

Comment: So my alternative solution is to use Outlook for IPhone. Do you think the same applies. Otherwise I will just have to use Mail for iPhone. I am moving to iCloud for ethical reasons.